# Pandas Series from dictionary/ summarized DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Here is some dummy data to show what my initial table looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Col_A","Col_B","Col_C"])
df.loc['2'] = pd.Series({"Col_A":.001,"Col_C":.4566})
df.loc['3'] = pd.Series({"Col_A":.25, "Col_B":.46})
df.loc['4'] = pd.Series({"Col_A":1, "Col_C":2})
df.loc['5'] = pd.Series({"Col_C":5.5})
```

Comes out like this:

```
    Col_A  Col_B   Col_C
2   0.001    NaN   0.4566
3   0.250    0.46   NaN
4   1.000    NaN   2.0000
5     NaN    NaN   5.5000
```

I would like to create a new dataframe with a summary of the non Null fields like so:

```
                        Column
Index
  2      'Col_A: 0.001 units; Col_C: 0.4566 units'
  3      'Col_A: 0.250 units; Col_B: 0.46 units'
  4      'Col_A: 1.000 units; Col_C: 2.0000 units'
  5      'Col_C: 5.5000 units'
```

I got as far as making this:

```
{'3': [('Col_A', 0.25), ('Col_B', 0.46)], '2': [('Col_A', 0.001), ('Col_C', nan)], '5': [('Col_C', nan)], '4': [('Col_A', 1.0), ('Col_C', nan)]}
```

But I cant figure out how to put it in the form above.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

1. `melt` your dataframe (wide-to-long conversion)
2. Drop NaNs using `dropna`
3. combine column names with values using `agg` + `str.join`
4. combine all values by index using `groupby` + `agg` + `str.join`

```
(df.reset_index()
   .melt('index')
   .dropna()
   .set_index('index')
   .astype(str)
   .agg(': '.join, 1)
   .add(' units') 
   .groupby(level=0)
   .agg('; '.join)
)

index
2    Col_A: 0.001 units; Col_C: 0.4566 units
3       Col_A: 0.25 units; Col_B: 0.46 units
4         Col_A: 1.0 units; Col_C: 2.0 units
5                           Col_C: 5.5 units
dtype: object
```

Note that this returns a `Series`.

---

**Option 2**

Replacing the `melt` with `stack` from Option 1;

```
(df.stack()
   .astype(str)
   .reset_index(level=1)
   .agg(': '.join, 1)
   .add(' units')
   .groupby(level=0)
   .agg('; '.join)
)

2    Col_A: 0.001 units; Col_C: 0.4566 units
3       Col_A: 0.25 units; Col_B: 0.46 units
4         Col_A: 1.0 units; Col_C: 2.0 units
5                           Col_C: 5.5 units
dtype: object
```

Comment: @Kdog, dude, you can only pick one answer as accepted answer , If I were you I will choose cold's answer , for my answer if you like you can upvote , that's it :-)

Comment: Will do. Really appreciate the help guys, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `stack`

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.name+":"+x.astype(str)+' units').mask(df.isnull()).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(';'.join)
Out[856]: 
2    Col_A:0.001 units;Col_C:0.4566 units
3       Col_A:0.25 units;Col_B:0.46 units
4         Col_A:1.0 units;Col_C:2.0 units
5                         Col_C:5.5 units
dtype: object
```